# URL affiliate in a <a href> with Nuxt (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an issue with a url.
My code :

```html
<a :href="gift.url_affiliate" target="_blank" class=" mr-2">Go to market</a>
```

This gift.url looks like :

```
https://www.awin1.com/cread.php?awinaffid=####&awinmid=####&clickref=####&**ued=https://www.onepiece.fr/fr-fr/combinaisons/classiques-de-lhiver/alpine-jumpsuit-black-2**
```

It seems that when there are two "https" in this string, nuxt disagree, and `<a>` is not displayed...

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to display there exactly? What should the link look like? Probably just a matter of properly escaping the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use `encodeURIComponent()` for that specific query part of the URL in case that it doesn't work without it. Encoding usually does not have any negative effect since it should work out of the box with most serverside code.

Comment: It creates a url : https:%2F%2Fwww.awin1.com%2Fcread.php%3Fawinaffid=####%26awinmid=####%26clickref=%26ued=https:%2F%2Fwww.onepiece.fr%2Ffr-fr%2Fcombinaisons%2Fclassiques-de-lhiver%2Fpolar-bears-are-coming-jumpsuit-dark-red that is not considered as an url :(

Comment: use it on the query only, so yo have to dissect that URL a bit using a regex for instance. You probably only need to encode the `ued` param since it is the only one containing conflicting characters.